# SparkR Shiny renderDT() with millions of rows

Tags: r, apache-spark, datatables, shiny, dt

I want to do [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) (lazily render a data table with millions of rows) in R Shiny, using the [`renderDT()`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) method with a [`SparkDataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) with millions of rows as my dataset. I'd like to be able to apply a global filter or column filters, as well. I haven't found any resources for doing this in R and I'm unable to translate the ajax at the first link to R code. Here's what I have so far:

> server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Connect to Spark outside the shinyServer() method
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]")

# Define server logic
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$myTable <- renderDT(

    # get the SparkDataFrame from HDFS; collect() converts SparkDataFrame -> data.frame
    collect(read.df(paste("hdfs://localhost:9000", input$path, sep=""), input$type))
  )
})
```

> ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a data table
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Simple SparkDataFrame Example"),

  # Sidebar with a text input for the filename 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("path",
                "HDFS File Path:",
                "/big_data/example_SQL/684c9b31-892c-48c5-8574-9dd61a9d7e78.parquet"
      ),
      textInput("type",
                "HDFS File Type:",
                "parquet"
      )
    ),

    # Show the table
    mainPanel(
       dataTableOutput("myTable")
    )
  )
))
```

The main issue I'm having right now is that `renderDT()` requires an R `data.frame`, so I'm using the [`collect()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/R/collect.html) method of SparkR to read the entire `SparkDataFrame` into memory, which is far from ideal. Can anyone help me work this out?

#### Update 0:

I've found the [extensions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) to R DataTables, so I reformat the table with a vertical scrollbar like this:

```
  output$myTable <- renderDT(

    # get the SparkDataFrame from HDFS; collect() converts SparkDataFrame -> data.frame
    collect(read.df(paste("hdfs://localhost:9000", input$path, sep=""), input$type)),

    extensions = "Scroller",

    options=list(
      deferRender = TRUE,
      scroller = TRUE,
      scrollY = 500  # height in pixels
    )
  )
```

But I'm still using `collect()` to convert the `SparkDataFrame` to a `data.frame`, which I want to avoid. *Additional question*: how do I enable `scroller.loadingIndicator` in R?

#### Update 1:

I think it has something to do with the [ajax()](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) method here, but I'm unable to translate this into R code or interpret it as JavaScript within R.

#### Update 2:

After much struggling, I've managed to get a MWE which is about 80% jQuery and 20% R. This reproduces the behavior at [this link](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html), but is done so with essentially no R code, which is not what I want:

```
library(shiny)

exscript <-
" $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      serverSide: true,
      ordering: false,
      searching: false, 
      ajax: function ( data, callback, settings ) {
        var out = [];

        for ( var i=data.start, ien=data.start+data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
          out.push( [ i+'-1', i+'-2', i+'-3', i+'-4', i+'-5' ] );
        }

        setTimeout( function () {
          callback( {
            draw: data.draw,
            data: out,
            recordsTotal: 5000000,
            recordsFiltered: 5000000
          } );
        }, 50 );
      },
      dom: 'rtiS',
      scrollY: 200,
      scroller: {
        loadingIndicator: true
      }
    } );
  } );"

minTable <-
" <table id='example'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>var1</td>
        <th>var2</th>
        <th>var3</th>
        <td>var4</td>
        <th>var5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="http://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.6/media/js/jquery.js")),
  tags$head(tags$script(src="http://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.6/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")),
  tags$head(tags$script(src="http://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.6/extensions/Scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.js")),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(exscript), type='text/javascript', language='javascript')),
  HTML(minTable)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { }

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```